# So I have different columns cn_ref_no,date,expiry,amount,cn_commission,cn_amount_tag,bill_ref_no,bill_commission,bill_amount_tag

Tags: mysql

So I have table with columns

The code I am using is

```
select distinct(a.cn_ref_no),a.cn_commission,a.cn_tag,b.b_ref,b.b_commission,b.b_tag,c.d_ref,c.d_tag,c.d_commission
from cn_table a
left join bill_table b
on a.cn_ref=b.our_lc_ref

left join disc_table c
on a.cn_ref=c.our_lc_ref
```

The table

| cn_ref_no | cn_commission | cn_tag | b_ref | b_commission | b_tag | d_ref | d_tag | d_commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 20 | BILL_EXC | D001 | DISC_SWF | 20 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 20 | BILL_EXC | D001 | DISC_ADV | 30 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 20 | BILL_EXC | D001 | DISC_CNF | 50 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 35 | BILL_ADV | D001 | DISC_SWF | 20 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 35 | BILL_ADV | D001 | DISC_ADV | 30 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 35 | BILL_ADV | D001 | DISC_CNF | 50 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 40 | BILL_SWF | D001 | DISC_SWF | 20 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 40 | BILL_SWF | D001 | DISC_ADV | 30 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 40 | BILL_SWF | D001 | DISC_CNF | 50 |

There are many differents records like this, this is one example.

What I want is data in this format

| cn_ref_no | cn_commission | cn_tag | b_ref | b_commission | b_tag | d_ref | d_tag | d_commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 20 | BILL_EXC | D001 | DISC_SWF | 20 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 35 | BILL_ADV | D001 | DISC_ADV | 30 |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 40 | BILL_SWF | D001 | DISC_CNF | 50 |

Or the records in a single row like this if possible

| cn_ref_no | cn_commission | cn_tag | b_ref | b_commission | b_tag | d_ref | d_tag | d_commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CN001 | 100 | CN_CNF | B001 | 20 35 40 | BILL_EXC BILL_ADV BILL_SWF | D001 | DISC_SWF DISC_ADV DISC_CNF | 20 30 50 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  could use group_concat and group by

```
Select a.cn_ref_no,a.cn_commission,a.cn_tag,b.b_ref,b.b_commission
  , group_concat(b.b_tag)
    ,c.d_ref
   ,group_concat(c.d_tag)
    ,c.d_commission
from cn_table a
left join bill_table b on a.cn_ref=b.our_lc_ref
left join disc_table c on a.cn_ref=c.our_lc_ref
group by a.cn_ref_no,a.cn_commission
    ,a.cn_tag,b.b_ref,b.b_commission, c.d_ref,c.d_commission
```

Comment: Any idea how I could do in spark sql?

Comment: @ddd .. this link could help you https://newbedev.com/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysql-s-group-concat-aggregate-function

Answer (score 1):

You can [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) the unique columns and the rest You can [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat), which can  use DISTINCT and ORDER BY

```
select a.cn_ref_no,a.cn_commission,a.cn_tag,b.b_ref,b.b_commission
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.b_tag),c.d_ref
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.d_tag)
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  c.d_commission ORDER BY c.d_commission ASC)
from cn_table a
left join bill_table b
on a.cn_ref=b.our_lc_ref

left join disc_table c
on a.cn_ref=c.our_lc_ref
GROUP BY a.cn_ref_no,a.cn_commission,a.cn_tag,b.b_ref,b.b_commission,c.d_ref
```

Comment: Any idea how I could do in spark sql?